# Evaluating integrals such as $\int x^5 \sqrt{x^3-2}dx$, making the radical "disapear" from the integrand

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals, substitution

I am still sharpening my integration skills and I noticed that when the integrand is involving radicals and some power of $x$ such as 
$$\int x^5 \sqrt{x^3-2}dx,$$
I can let $\alpha=\sqrt{x^3-2}$ such that $\alpha^2+2=x^3$ and get $\frac 23 \alpha\, d\alpha = x^2dx$ which creates a neat substitution into $\alpha$ terms  that makes the radical vanish and I get a result right away.

$$\begin{align}
\int x^5 \sqrt{x^3-2}dx & = \int \left(x^3\right)\left(\sqrt{x^3-2}\right)\left(x^2dx\right) \\
& = \int \left(\alpha^2+2\right)\left(\alpha\right)\left(\frac 23 \alpha\,d\alpha\right) \\
& = \frac 23 \int \alpha^4+2\alpha^2\,d\alpha \\
& = \frac 2{15}\alpha^5+\frac 49 \alpha^3 \\
& = \frac 2{15}\left(x^3-2\right)^{5/2}+\frac 49 \left(x^3-2\right)^{3/2}+C
\end{align}$$

I am not sure about this substitution, is it correct? I am not trying by any means to avoid doing the work of using integration by parts or other substitution techniques here, but rather I wonder if what I am doing with the radical and the differential in my substitution is allowed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are correct. One way of checking your answer is integral calculator or wolfram alpha.

Comment: You can also just differentiate your answer to check.

Comment: Many integral techniques, at least when used in practice, can be very hand-wavey, even when they're originally based on firm, theoretical ground. You find yourself asking questions like "can I even use substitution here?" and so on. That's OK. As long as you differentiate your result afterwards to check.